# How to train/fine tune with images containing multiple languages?

Tags: tesseract

When extracting wordstrboxes I supply the languages the image contains, for example "eng+deu", however lstmf is created per language.

tesseract.exe image.png image --psm 4 -l eng+deu wordstrbox

So what is the correct path forward here? Use the images both in training for English and for German? Or something else?

Thanks

Comment: When fine tuning eng using the box file containing German characters, I get this error;

`Encoding of string failed! Failure bytes: c3 a4 6e 65 6d 61 72 6b 20
Can't encode transcription: 'D├ñnemark ' in language ''`

Should be 'Dänemark '. The box file is in UTF8 (no BOM) and with Linux line endings

Comment: NB! Using same LSTMF with deu gives no errors.

Someone might say that the German chars should be removed from the box file when using it for english, but not really practical for me.
What technically happens when this error occurs. Will it break the eng traineddata, or just skip the wordstr that it cannot encode?

Comment: Might be practical after all, but needs do to additional steps. Using unicharset_extractor I can extract unicharset for box file and do the same per language using combine_tessdata -e. Comparing chars between these, I can narrow down on which strings belong to which language and thereby generate separate box files per language before fine tuning. Question if this is needed or not? Depends on what happens when Encoding error occurs. Is there anybody out there?

Comment: When fine tuning English, the image will still contain "Dänemark", but the ground truth box file will then have no wordstr for this. Will this be good, or would it be better to have it as "Danemark" when fine tuning English? That would make it much harder. I hope the encoding error does not matter and does not affect output